# Use Windows.Storage.ApplicationData object and his RoamingSettings property for save SerializableDictionary

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, roaming

In the code-behind of a page of Windows 8.1 app, I create a `SerializableDictionary:`

```
private static SerializableDictionary<string, Persona> elenco =
                                  new SerializableDictionary<string, Persona>();
```

where, the `SerializableDictionary` class is [this.](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx) How can I save `elenco` using `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData` object and his `RoamingSettings` property? (If it helps, even changing the declarations `private static`).

Answer (score 0):

Well, since it's serializable, I guess one way would be to serialize it to a string and store that string in RoamingSettings. Something like this:

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder);
elenco.WriteXml(xmlWriter);
var applicationData = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current;
applicationData.RoamingSettings.Values["elenco"] = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

I haven't actually used RoamingSettings though, so I could be way off. Here's how you'd read the data back out:

```
var applicationData = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current;
var elencoXml = (string)applicationData.RoamingSettings.Values["elenco"];
var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(elencoXml));
elenco.ReadXml(xmlReader);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems to work. Now, how can I perform the reverse operation, that is read from `RoamingSettings` and save to a `SerializableDictionary?`

Comment: It looks like the end of your last comment is missing. Are you saying you don't know how to get your data into the SerializableDictionary to begin with? The SerializableDictionary class you posted can be used as a normal dictionary:
    elenco["some key"] = new Persona();

Comment: Thank you very much! I want to post a reply to show the code but I can not for the next 8 hours. I do not have enough reputation.